# Javascript and rickshaw. How do I update realtime streaming?

Tags: javascript, rickshaw

How to I update rickshaw data with real time streaming?

I initiate a chart as follows.

```
for (var i = 0; i < json_data.length; i++) {
    meta = json_data[i];
    seriesJsonData.push({color: palette.color(),data: meta['series'],name: meta['name']});
}
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
    element: document.getElementById("chart"),
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    renderer: 'area',
    stroke: true,
    series: seriesJsonData
} );
```

I then want to do a call back to get data in this format.

```
//new data to plot.
setInterval( function() {
    // data = mycallback('ajax_time_series/');
    data = {y: 0.013342943046016261, x: 1362914220};
    graph.series.addData(data);
    graph.update();
}, 3000 );

json_data = [{"series": [{y: 0.013342943046016261, x: 1362914220}, {y: 0.03332711471721182, x: 1362914280}, {y: 0.01995987637052034, x: 1362914340}, {y: 0.02667808501229039, x: 1362914400}, {y: 0.026667576407988548, x: 1362914460}, {y: 0.02666090465447435, x: 1362914520}, {y: 0.039902022061890564, x: 1362914580}, {y: 0.040065222851502304, x: 1362914640}, {y: 0.026725544622339118, x: 1362914700}, {y: 0.03328597880035014, x: 1362914760}, {y: 0.020025583265634844, x: 1362914820}, {y: 0.013351483328567889, x: 1362914880}, {y: 0.013327807174645642, x: 1362914940}, {y: 0.03327930933245091, x: 1362915000}, {y: 0.060011496243413356, x: 1362915060}, {y: 0.026726823599964183, x: 1362915120}, {y: 0.06625748681407234, x: 1362915180}, {y: 0.08716853007016215, x: 1362915240}, {y: 0.019958925851731625, x: 1362915300}, {y: 0.026628071716283376, x: 1362915360}, {y: 0.053539335295842476, x: 1362915420}, {y: 0.013329419200217766, x: 1362915480}, {y: 0.020005110867173173, x: 1362915540}, {y: 0.03985835992510624, x: 1362915600}, {y: 0.04009389940367332, x: 1362915660}, {y: 0.020015945088387825, x: 1362915720}, {y: 0.02661011443819408, x: 1362915780}, {y: 0.06656881334811096, x: 1362915840}, {y: 0.04690556277785193, x: 1362915900}, {y: 0.03326433994636323, x: 1362915960}, {y: 0.02670133346693278, x: 1362916020}, {y: 0.033335701795225714, x: 1362916080}, {y: 0.020001391989344027, x: 1362916140}, {y: 0.02000903195967164, x: 1362916200}, {y: 0.013308784414422375, x: 1362916260}, {y: 0.058279492803009744, x: 1362916320}, {y: 0.034243644495436376, x: 1362916380}, {y: 0.020081534665136593, x: 1362916440}, {y: 0.026653921622562717, x: 1362916500}, {y: 0.0199648119499449, x: 1362916560}, {y: 0.03338215889686262, x: 1362916620}, {y: 0.04659716637539024, x: 1362916680}, {y: 0.033199969663029336, x: 1362916740}, {y: 0.020053008656297493, x: 1362916800}, {y: 0.020083574882737414, x: 1362916860}, {y: 0.013338712371294185, x: 1362916920}, {y: 0.013285462289789874, x: 1362916980}, {y: 0.03342980523147545, x: 1362917040}, {y: 0.013318560614522242, x: 1362917100}, {y: 0.020054761094019935, x: 1362917160}, {y: 0.02649323226604952, x: 1362917220}, {y: 0.08046447455222104, x: 1362917280}, {y: 0.033380214683152935, x: 1362917340}, {y: 0.01998459181555401, x: 1362917400}, {y: 0.11263974301203006, x: 1362917460}, {y: 0.03351645707155687, x: 1362917520}, {y: 0.02667373118205504, x: 1362917580}, {y: 0.020004237840478896, x: 1362917640}, {y: 0.0867493421006396, x: 1362917700}], "name": "cpuUsage"}];
```

I will have multiple series to update.  My charts don't update and I dont understand the documents to update.

Also...I am not committed with rickshaw.  Is there a real-time streaming JS library that has good documentation?  Rickshaw looks pretty but real time is poorly documented.

Comment: Note.  I abandoned rickshaw.  There is no support and the documentation is not very good.  Instead I am using flot. Great documentation and user support and simply works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to let you know about my workaround for this:

1. Save the inner html of the chart div for later use (after the chart has been rendered, the inner html is altered)
2. When you add data, add it to an array that you can access later.
3. Render the chart as normally with the array of data.
4. When you need to add data, add the data to the array that contains your data and regenerate the chart from scratch. You can only do this if you insert the original html back in the chart div's again before you render again.

This works well with 8 charts updated every 5 seconds with 20 data points per chart. It takes up virtually no resources. I'm sure it would require a lot if you increase the amount of data points or use advanced rendering options.

I should get the workaround nobel prize for this.

Comment: Could you post some code for this work around? I'm having the same trouble updating a graph.

Comment: I don't have any code that is not tightly integrated in other code. Which part of my description is unclear to you?

Answer (score 2):

For those who come behind, the [FixedDuration series](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Series.FixedDuration.js) is probably what you want.

It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere except in [this example demonstrating real time updates with a fixed window](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/fixed.html), but [it's been around since before the v1.1 release in August 2012](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/v1.1.0/src/js/Rickshaw.Series.FixedDuration.js).

Here's the code for generating the plot in their example:

```
var tv = 250;

// instantiate our graph!
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
    element: document.getElementById("chart"),
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    renderer: 'line',
    series: new Rickshaw.Series.FixedDuration([{ name: 'one' }], undefined, {
        timeInterval: tv,
        maxDataPoints: 100,
        timeBase: new Date().getTime() / 1000
    }) 
} );

graph.render();

// add some data every so often

var i = 0;
var iv = setInterval( function() {

    var data = { one: Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 120 };

    var randInt = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    data.two = (Math.sin(i++ / 40) + 4) * (randInt + 400);
    data.three = randInt + 300;

    graph.series.addData(data);
    graph.render();

}, tv );
```